# Узнать ip сервера из javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть ли способ определить внешний ip-адрес сервера из javascript?
Или преобразовать доменное имя в ip-адрес?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102605/can-i-lookup-the-ip-address-of-a-hostname-from-javascript

Comment: @metalurgus я там был, но что то ничего подходящего не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `PHP`.

```
<?php
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $ip = gethostbyname($domain);
    echo "IP сервера: " . $ip;
?>
```

Comment: А это работает?

Comment: Обращаю внимание, ip адрес сервера, а не клиента

Comment: @KYRAN как вариант, но опять же. при этом нужно знать доменное имя.

Comment: @dnalchemist обновил ответттт

Answer (score 1):

Можно обратиться к сторонним сервисам, как было сказано выше.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function z (x){ ip = x.query }</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ip-api.com/json/zero.eu.org?callback=z'></script>
```

Но мне это не подходит, поскольку домен может быть расположен внутри сети.
Единственный способ, что я нашел, это послать доменное имя к сервлету, по которому он сможет обратиться сам к себе, и узнать свой ip-адрес, и отдать его клиенту.
Лучшего способа я не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Так сделать нельзя.

Можно написать или воспользоваться простым сервисом, который на стороне сервера выполняет эту работу в ответ на ajax-запрос.

Comment: Сервер же не может знать свой внешний ip?

Comment: @dnalchemist почему? для особо хитрых случаев вы на сервере через dns преобразуете в ip

Comment: Что то я не совсем понимаю. Под сервисом вы же не имеете ввиду сторонние сервисы в интернете? Как получить свой внешний айпи за роутером и провайдером на джаве, ума не приложу. Только локальный адрес в роутере мне вернет он.

Comment: Ну или свой или сторонний. Если по Имени нельзя определить адрес, то интернет бы вообще не работал. DNS вам в помощь

Comment: А, ну тогда я правильно мысль понял. Блин, почему в джаваскрипте то нельзя. Плохо это